# How to check if XML value exist?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I'm trying to get data from XML. What I know is that I always get an error when the animal i'm trying to find is not in the XML data. An example as shown.

This is the data stored in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
<Animal value="Elephant" size="2" name="Bob">
    <Action age="1" size="1">I am small</Action>
    <Action age="2" size="1">I am growing up</Action>
    <Action age="3" size="1">I'm 3 years old</Action>
    <Action age="4" size="1">I'm BIG</Action>
</Animal>
</Root>
```

This is part of the C# coding:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("animals.xml");
string animal = "Elephant";
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Animal[@value='" + animal + "']")
                                     .Attributes["name"].InnerText));
```

The error occurs when I change

```
string animal = "Tiger";
```

How do I solve the error if the data does not exist?

Comment: A hint is to find out what `xDoc.SelectSingleNode()` returns for the different values you supply.

Comment: Verify if `xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Animal[@value='" + animal + "']")` is `null` before you invoke any methods on it.

Comment: What you are trying to get from xml? There is only one Animal node. You are trying to check if it's `value` attribute has specified value?

Comment: from the code i provided, I would get back "Elephant"

Comment: @MeowMeow you are passing `Elephant` and want to get back `Elephant` what is purpose of this?

Comment: I typed the wrong line, let me change it.

Comment: Now i should get "Bob" from the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq to Xml to get name of animal (it will return `null` if animal was not found):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("animals.xml");
string animal = "Elephant";

var name = xdoc.Root.Elements()
                .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("value") == animal)
                .Select(a => (string)a.Attribute("name"))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also you can simply check if any animal matching your value was found, and get name only if there is match:

```
var xpath = String.Format("Root/Animal[@value='{0}']", animal);
var animalElement = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);

if (animalElement != null)
    MessageBox.Show((string)animalElement.Attribute("name"));
```

Comment: using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

I have all this three but the error says:
Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XNode'
Error 2 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'XPathSelectElement' and the best extension method overload 'System.Xml.XPath.Extensions.XPathSelectElement(System.Xml.Linq.XNode, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @MeowMeow `xdoc` is a `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument`. That is Linq to Xml, which is better to use for xml parsing

Comment: changed it to XDocument still cannot use XPathSelectElement

Comment: @MeowMeow make sure you have namespace `using System.Xml.XPath` defined. This extension method defined in System.Xml.Xpath namespace

Comment: i did add using System.Xml.XPath;

Comment: @MeowMeow strange. Are you sure you are using `XDocument` from `using System.Xml.Linq` namespace?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33853/discussion-between-meowmeow-and-lazyberezovsky)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectNodes` as an `XmlNodeList` instead, then examine its node count. If the count is zero, say "node not found"; otherwise, grab the attribute, and print it:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("animals.xml");
string animal = "Tiger";
XmlNodeList theList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/Root/Animal[@value='" + animal + "']");
if (theList.Count == 1) {
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(theList[0].Attributes["value"].InnerText));
} else if (theList.Count == 0) {
    MessageBox.Show("No "+animal);
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Multiple "+animal+"s");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var animalNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Animal[@value='" + animal + "']");
if (animalNode != null)
{
  var valueAttr = animalNode.Attributes["value"];
  if (valueAttr != null)
  {  
     MessageBox.Show(valueAttr.InnerText); //.value ???
  }
}
```